# get reference of new dynamicly created MediaPlayer instance

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, media-player

I am trying to create a `C#` app that have dynamically created number of buttons , each button have `Click_Handler` that if clicked plays a sound depending on a file that the user specified earlier.

every thing is working and all the sounds plays at the same time using this simple function

```
private void playSound (string path)
{
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer mp = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
                mp.Open(new System.Uri(path));
                mp.Play();
            }
    }
```

Now each time a user clicks on any button it will start playing sound using new instance of the `MediaPlayer` object

My question is how can I get a reference to each newly created `MediaPlayer` object so that I can manipulate it (stop,pause,timeline ...etc)

Comment: why are you creating a common object of System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer? you can create a different object for different mp3.

Comment: my app can contain more than hundred button and the user should be able to play them all at the same time if he pleased, I am trying to make it dynamic as i could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the instance after calling the method:

```
private System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer playSound (string path)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
       System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer mp = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
       mp.Open(new System.Uri(path));
       mp.Play();

       return mp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

In your calling code check if returned object is not null before using:

```
var mp = playSound(@"d:\music\file.mp3");
if(mp != null)
{
   //do something with mp
}
```

You can also keep this MediaPlayer object in a dictionary object for easy manipulation.

```
Dictionary<string, System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer> players = new Dictionary<string, System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer>();
var mp = playSound(@"d:\music\file.mp3");
players.Add(btn.Text, mp); //Identifying media player by button text
// Later if a user press the button again and your default action is pause
if(players.ContainsKey(btn.Text))
   players[btn.Text].Pause();
```